# Generating filetree dictionary from list of files in Python?

Tags: python

Trying to figure out the easiest way to do this. I have a list of all files on a server. I want to rewrite this list as a dictionary that better represents the filetree.

What I have:

`"study/patient/visitNumber/C1/", "study/patient/visitNumber/C1/subject_14Jan16_V17_C1a.mp4", "study/patient/visitNumber/C1/subject_14Jan16_V17_C1b.mp4", "study/patient/visitNumber/C2/", "study/patient/visitNumber/C2/subject_14Jan16_V17_C2a.mp4", "study/patient/visitNumber/C2/study_subject_V17_C2.mp4", "study/patient/visitNumber/master/C1/subject_14Jan16_V17_C1a.MTS",`

What I want

```
   {"parentFolder":{
          "childFolder":{
             "file":"filename",
             "grandChildFolder":{"etc...":""}
           }
           "childFolder2":{
             "file":"filename2",
             "grandChildFolder2":{"etc...":""}
           }
    }}
```

There are over 6000 items in the list, and the folder structure is really inconsistent, so I'm having trouble splitting the filenames by folder and knowing how to add them to the dictionary. I suspect recursion? Thanks.

Comment: could you be more specific - "I want to rewrite this list as a dictionary that better represents the filetree"

Comment: @pySam1459 Sure. rewriting my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code iterates through the files list, and creates/amends the tree depending on the path. Each directory 'node' has key-value pairs of each sub-directory and 1 key-value pair 'files', which is a list of all files in that directory.
Note that this code only works if all files in the list start from the same root directory.

```py
// files = [...]

tree = {"files": []}

for file in files:
    dirs = file.strip(r"/").split(r"/")
    c = tree
    for i, d in enumerate(dirs):
        if "." in d:
            c["files"].append(d)
        else:
            if d not in c:
                c[d] = {"files": []}

            c = c[d]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked.